# My dual booted Ubuntu heating up

Tags: 20.04, power-management

I've dual booted and using Ubuntu on my Elitebook 820 G2. It's working fine, but it's been heating up lately. It works perfectly on the second OS (windows) though, so this is not a fan problem.

I've installed different software but not rectifying the problem at all.

Here are my system's specs:

- OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- OS Type: 64-bit
- GNOME Version: 3.36.3
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
- Graphics: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2)

Comment: AFAIK, Ubuntu doesn't have the same level of power managment as Windows, so your laptop makes more heat

Comment: run top and see if there are any processes not running as they should (I had a similar problem and there was an xembedns process I have to kill on each startup until I determine what spawns it)

Comment: Actually you should start by updating UEFI.

Comment: You mention Ubuntu 20.04 & GNOME, and installing different software, but have tagged kubuntu & lubuntu.  It might help if you clarify exactly what you have, and how KDE/Kubuntu & LXQt/Lubuntu relate  (both are Qt environments unlike GNOME which is GTK, that will impact resources esp. RAM but I doubt it'd create heat issues unless you have limited RAM & thus it's *thrashing*... Please provide details on why you tagged what you did.